# Preview an html page without opening it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

On click a image how can another page be  previewed in the same page without opening the actual page. Lets say the url `/home/home.php?id=3`
The preview should be in the preview div:

```
 <img src="/home/app/img/toggle.gif" onlclick="show();" />
 <div id="preview"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for this. Here's an example, HTML like this:

```
<img src="/home/app/img/toggle.gif" id="previewBtn" />
<div id="preview"></div>
```

jQuery like this:

```
$("#previewBtn").click(function() {
  $("#preview").load("/home/home.php?id=3");
});
```

---

Or, if you had lots of previews, something like this more generic works:

```
<a class="previewBtn" href="/home/home?id=1">Preview 1</a>
<a class="previewBtn" href="/home/home?id=2">Preview 2</a>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

With this jQuery:

```
$(".previewBtn").click(function() {
  $("#preview").load(this.href);
});
```

Comment: And it will just open the link in preview mode rit?

Comment: @Hulk yes - it will load the entire content of that page into the preview div, if you just want a portion, say the page's stuff that mattered was in a `<div id="content">` element, you can do this: `$("#preview").load("/home/home.php?id=3 #content");` and it'll load only that section.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '2.htm',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: That's an awfully long way to write `$('.result').load('2.html')` :)

Comment: awefully long but unit testable. they didnt design the success for nothing. its to get alerts about where your code is going wrong as you app gets bigger

Comment: `.load()` also has a success callback, and status text, see for yourself: http://api.jquery.com/load/ :)

Comment: well then it would be as long mate :)